# cc.net: set subject email publisher from trigger name

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

folks!
I have project in cc.net and this project nay start by 3 ways

1. Forced (when user click button "force" in web
2. By project trigger
3. By sheduler trigger

After build server send mail to stackholders.

And now, i want to add trigger name to mail subject. e.g.
force_Project name ...buikd result

I have tried use variables:

```
<projectTrigger project="Someproject">
    <triggerStatus>Success</triggerStatus>
<variable name="Trigger" value="commit" />          
</projectTrigger>
```

and

```
<subjectSettings>    
<subject buildResult="Broken" value="{Trigger} is  broken" />
<subject buildResult="StillBroken" value="{Trigger} is still broken" />    
</subjectSettings>
```

but this way doesnt have positive result.

What kind of way able help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fileLabeller of ccnet.

```
   <tasks>
     build tasks...
     <fileLabeller> 
        <labelFilePath>c:\buildstuff\mybuild-label.txt</labelFilePath> 
        <allowDuplicateSubsequentLabels>false</allowDuplicateSubsequentLabels> 
     </fileLabeller> 
   </tasks>
```

Setup your build task to write to the contents of mybuild-label.txt. I write something like this.

[repo1 rev: 99, repo2 rev: 9999]

This will become part of the subject.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I am going to try it.